# for row in rows is working in one statement but not the next (python 3.4, sqlite3)

Tags: python, debugging, sqlite

```
def ConnecttoCurrency():
conn = sqlite3.connect('E:\python\Player_Currency.sqlite')

print('Right before conn')
with conn:
    print('I have entered currency')
    conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Player_Curren")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        global primecolumn, Currency_Name, amount,money
        print('im in Row of rows')
        primecolumn, Currency_Name, amount = (
            row["pkcolumn"], row["Currency_Name"], row["amount"])
        money = amount
        print('HEY I GOT INTO THE ROW LOOP')
        print(amount)
    return money
```

This isn't out putting print im in row of rows, but

```
def DeleteItemAndReturnSilver():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('E:\python\Player_Inv_Database.sqlite')

    with conn:
        conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Player_Inv")
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        money = 0
        for row in rows:  # gets Item from monster loot table
            print('Im in delteitemrows')
            global Item_c, Item_N, Pr, Number_Of_I, money
            Item_c, Item_N, Pr, Number_Of_I = (
                row["pkcolumn"], row["Item_Name"], row["Price"], row["Number_Of_Item"])

            money = Pr + money
            query = 'DELETE FROM Player_Inv WHERE pkcolumn=?'
            cur.execute(query, (Item_column,))

            print(money)
        return money
```

but this works, and prints im in delete itemsrow, Im lost and its confusing me because its making no since. Thanks for helping

Comment: You have different dbs: is that deliberate? i.e. `Player_Currency.sqlite` and   `Player_Inv_Database.sqlite`

Comment: yea, one is just for currency, wow there is something wrong with my database calls thank so much.. ive been looking at it like what is going on rawr

Comment: If it prints 'I have entered currency' you need to check the `SELECT` statement next. Is the table called `Player_Curren`?

Comment: Yea the table is called Player_curren